# Button visibility depending on inputs focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, visibility

I have the DOM:

```
<input type='text'>
<button>Add</button>
```

and the CSS:

```
button {
    visibility: hidden;
}

input:focus + button {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here we can see that our button is visible only when input element is focused. I've added click listener to the button, but it doesn't work.

But if to add transition to button it works. But unfortunately transitions only IE10+.

```
button {
    transition: visibility 1s ease;
}
```

Question: Is there another css way to work this (without javascripts focus/blur)?

Comment: try adding button:focus{
  visibility: visible;
}
 also

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `opacity` instead of `visibility`. It atleast fires the click event of button.

```css
button {
    opacity:0;
}

input:focus + button {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<button onclick="alert('Hello')">Add</button>
```

Comment: note that using `opacity` will allow to click the button even if it's not visible

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to use `hover` and add `visibility: visible`

will give you the ability to press the button when you move the mouse over the button. but first you must have the cursor on the input, as expected

```css
   

 button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
    button:hover{
visibility: visible;
}
    input:focus + button {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<button onclick="alert('Hello')">Add</button>
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you click on the button, the input loses focus and the button immediately disappears, so it will never receive a click. In this case I would suggest using a little `transition-delay` and adding `button:focus` class, for example like that:

```
input:focus + button,
button:focus {
    visibility: visible;
}

button {
    transition: visibility 0s ease 50ms;
}
```

This will keep your button visible for additional 50 miliseconds after losing focus on the input (so you have additional 50ms to get the click registered) and then when the button is focused, it doesn't disappear, because we added another CSS condition to prevent that.

This is not the best solution, but without using JavaScript, this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Thank you. But transition doesn't work in IE9. http://caniuse.com/css-transitions/embed/

Comment: I don't know what are your requirements, but you should know that IE9 accounts only for 0.2% of all browsers used nowadays. Moreover a year ago Microsoft announced the end of support for IE10, 9 and 8, so why would your website support a browser that even its producer does not.